# Write in memory object to S3 via boto3

Tags: amazon-s3, python-3.6, boto3, cstringio

I am attempting to write files directly to S3 without creating a local file which is then uploaded.

I am using cStringIO to generate a file in memory, but I am having trouble figuring out the proper way to upload it in boto3.

```
def writetos3(sourcedata, filename, folderpath):
     s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
     data = open(sourcedata, 'rb')
     s3.Bucket('bucketname').put_object(Key= folderpath + "/" + filename, Body=data)
```

Above is the standard boto3 method that I was using previously with the local file, it does not work without a local file, I get the following error: `coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, cStringIO.StringO found`
.

Because the in memory file (I believe) is already considered open, I tried changing it to the code below, but it still does not work, no error is given the script simply hangs on the last line of the method.

```
def writetos3(sourcedata, filename, folderpath):
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    s3.Bucket('bucketname').put_object(Key= folderpath + "/" + filename, Body=sourcedata)
```

Just for more info, the value I am attempting to write looks like this

`(cStringIO.StringO object at 0x045DC540)`

Does anyone have an idea of what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: When I use the original method the error I get is this:

TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, cStringIO.StringO found.

When I use the second method the program just hangs, getting stuck on the last line of the writetos3 method

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want this:

```
    data = open(sourcedata, 'rb').decode()
```

It defaults to utf8. Also, I encourage you to run your code under python3, and to use appropriate language tags for your question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I was planning on upgrading to 3.0 but I just went ahead and converted the script now.

After converting the syntax and running the method with your suggested change I am now getting the following error:

TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.StringIO

Comment: I ended up solving the problem by simply converting the stringIO object to a string before passing it to the writetoS3 method.